# Inner class create fail in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

This code sample cannot be compiled and shows an internal error.

```
open class TestClass {
    open inner class Back {
        open fun dd() { }
    }
}

class Manager: TestClass() {
    private val test = object : Back() {
        override fun dd() { }
    }
}
```

Cause:

> Error generating constructors of class null with kind IMPLEMENTATION

What does it mean?

Comment: This is definitely a bug, could you please file an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT?

Comment: I post issue at [KT-11846](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11846)

Answer (score 0):

The example provided refers to [KT-11833](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11833) and now compiles. Checked it with Kotlin version 1.1.0-beta-22.